# Ansible inventory group array pointer to parent

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I want to check if anyone knows if there is a solution to this problem I am facing in Ansible.

I have a inventory file that looks like this:-

```
[clusterA]
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2
10.0.0.3
....

[clusterB]
10.1.0.1
10.1.0.2
10.1.0.3
....

[web-lb]
10.0.0.1
10.1.0.1
```

Instead of repeating the IP address in `web-lb` group, I want to do something like this:-

```
[web-lb:children]
clusterA[0]
clusterB[0]
```

If we can script the group as mentioned above, I don't need to duplicate IP addresses, and i can mix different item from a group into another group, Eg

```
[webA-lb:children]
clusterA[1]
clusterA[5]
clusterB[3]
```

**UPDATED**

Having the below configuration doesn't work as well

```
[webA-lb]
clusterA[1]
```

Error:

```
bbed5901ea74:~$ ansible -i hosts all --list-hosts
hosts (6):
10.1.0.1
10.1.0.2
10.1.0.3
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2
10.0.0.3
bbed5901ea74:~$ vi hosts
bbed5901ea74:~$ ansible -i hosts all --list-hosts
ERROR! Attempted to read "hosts" as YAML: Syntax Error while loading YAML.


The error appears to have been in '/home/jenkins/hosts': line 2, column 1, 
but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

[clusterA]
10.0.0.1
^ here

Attempted to read "hosts" as ini file: host range must be begin:end or 
begin:end:step
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use `:children` combined with the individual selector `[]` like that.  The `:children` suffix denotes a group of groups.

So you could do this:

```
[web-lb]
clusterA[0]
clusterB[0]
```

But not this:

```
[web-lb:children]
clusterA[0]
clusterB[0]
```

See Ansible's [Patterns](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_patterns.html) and [Inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html#groups-of-groups-and-group-variables) documentation for more details. Ansible is very flexible. You can also use the `!` symbol to exclude certain children from a group.

Comment: I did try the approach you have mentioned and ansible doesn't seems to understand even we omitted the `children` tag in the group.

Comment: Hmm... do you know why it's saying it's trying to read your `hosts` file as YAML when it's INI syntax?

Comment: The moment I have the square bracket in the group, this error happens.  I then change the `hosts` to `hosts.ini` and try one more time and I got this error  `29286d512845:~$ ansible -i hosts.ini all --list-hosts
ERROR! Attempted to read "hosts.ini" as ini file: host range must be begin:end or begin:end:step`

Comment: @jlim [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41095437/5463636) has a good guide for how to format hosts in a YAML file. I don't know why your syntax isn't working as an INI file, though.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  If I understand the ansible `inventory` correctly, the `pattern` usage can be applied to host machines like `192.168.2.[100-110]`, but it cannot use on a group.  From a `playbook` perspective, you can apply group patterns like `hosts: clusterA[1]`.  Nevertheless, I have given up on this approach of how I want to layout my `inventory` file in the way I wanted in my earlier post.

Comment: I have gone ahead to test once more with YAML from the link you have provided.  It does show the same error `host range must be begin:end or begin:end:step`.  I am concluding that you cannot assign pattern on group in a children or another group itself.  You can perform pattern on host instead