# mysql_replication_role is default or user defined? If User defined, How can I set it in my playbook?

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-facts

In Ansible to install MySQL, I used a property in my config like the below code

```
{% if mysql_replication_master %}
# Replication
server-id = {{ mysql_server_id }}

{% if mysql_replication_role == 'master' %}
log_bin = mysql-bin
log-bin-index = mysql-bin.index
expire_logs_days = {{ mysql_expire_logs_days }}
max_binlog_size = {{ mysql_max_binlog_size }}
binlog_format = {{mysql_binlog_format}}

{% for db in mysql_databases %}
{% if db.replicate|default(1) %}
binlog_do_db = {{ db.name }}
{% else %}
binlog_ignore_db = {{ db.name }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{% if mysql_replication_role == 'slave' %}
read_only
relay-log = relay-bin
relay-log-index = relay-bin.index
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

How do I set mysql_replication_role = master and mysql_replication_role = slave in my playbook while installing MySql.

And my Inventory file code like this

```
master:
    10.0.0.1
    20.0.0.1
slave: 
    10.0.0.2
    20.0.0.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I set mysql_replication_role = master and mysql_replication_role = slave in my playbook

This is a property you want to assign to the target server, so you shouldn't do it in a playbook, but in the inventory, for example:

```
[my_hosts]
srv123 mysql_replication_role=master
srv456 mysql_replication_role=slave
```

Similarly you could set it in host_vars, group_vars, which are considered a part of the inventory, depending on how you want to organise your inventory; Ansible is flexible in this respect.

Read more on the [Working with Inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html) page.

Comment: Hi, 
 I added my inventory file code in this qstn. As per your suggestion, how can I set properties inside the config based on hosts.

Comment: Please read the above answer. If you are asking about using YAML for the inventory, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41095437/2947502).