# How do I use an encrypted variable (ansible_ssh_pass) in an INI file?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am reading [this page](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/network/getting_started/first_inventory.html#protecting-sensitive-variables-with-ansible-vault) and if I drop the following text in an file in the Inventory folder :

```
[vyos:vars]
ansible_connection=network_cli
ansible_network_os=vyos
ansible_user=my_vyos_user
ansible_ssh_pass= !vault |
       $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.2;AES256;my_user
       66386134653765386232383236303063623663343437643766386435663632343266393064373933
       3661666132363339303639353538316662616638356631650a316338316663666439383138353032
       63393934343937373637306162366265383461316334383132626462656463363630613832313562
       3837646266663835640a313164343535316666653031353763613037656362613535633538386539
       65656439626166666363323435613131643066353762333232326232323565376635
```

I am getting this error message

```
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /home/myuser/Ansible/Inventory/pwdtest
with ini plugin: /home/cristi/Ansible/Inventory/pwdtest:9: Expected
key=value, got: $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.2;AES256;my_user
```

I think the issue comes down to assigning a multiline string to a variable in an INI file

Does anybody have any idea how I can use this?
I can use the above in a YAML file format but I would like to keep consistency and use YAML everywhere

Comment: Add information to question (not in the comments), the relevant ansible code and the complete command you use to launch the playbook

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How do I use an encrypted variable (ansible_ssh_pass) in an INI file?

You can't.

The [documentation page you linked to](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/network/getting_started/first_inventory.html#protecting-sensitive-variables-with-ansible-vault), seems to be blatantly wrong.

For a start, `!vault` tag and `|` character in the output of `ansible-vault` belong to YAML syntax and there is no way they could ever work in an INI-format inventory.

It seems also, that the function `AnsibleVaultEncryptedUnicode`, which decrypts the value, [is called only from the YAML parser](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/39182552ef02ca58a44569f2974836f05317546b/lib/ansible/parsing/yaml/constructor.py#L108), so there is no way to modify the value (like single line, no tag) in the INI-format inventory.

---

You can either:

- [write your inventory in YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41094864/2947502), whole or a part of it, if you use a directory and split the inventory into  multiple files
- create a directory `group_vars` in the same directory as your inventory file and put a file `vyos.yml` inside with the following content:

  ```
  ansible_connection: network_cli
  ansible_network_os: vyos
  ansible_user: my_vyos_user
  ansible_ssh_pass: !vault |
    $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.2;AES256;my_user
    66386134653765386232383236303063623663343437643766386435663632343266393064373933
    3661666132363339303639353538316662616638356631650a316338316663666439383138353032
    63393934343937373637306162366265383461316334383132626462656463363630613832313562
    3837646266663835640a313164343535316666653031353763613037656362613535633538386539
    65656439626166666363323435613131643066353762333232326232323565376635
  ```